# Codeigniter4 redirect()->to() is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

On CI4, I'm trying to redirect the user to `admin/login` when the admin is not loggedin.

`$this->session->isAdminLoggedIn` is working as it should. But when I goto `admin/index` the user is not redirected and the statement `echo __METHOD__;` is being executed. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers\Admin;

use CodeIgniter\Controller;
use App\Controllers\BaseController;


use Config\Services;

class Admin extends BaseController{

    protected $session;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->session = Services::session();
    }

    private function admin_login_check(){
        if ( !$this->session->isAdminLoggedIn ){
            $R2 = urlencode( current_url() );
            return redirect()->to('admin/login?r2='.$R2);
        }
    }

    public function index(){
        $this->admin_login_check();
        echo __METHOD__;
    }

}
```

Comment: Does the redirection work if you return `$this->admin_login_check()`?

Comment: You mean return $this->admin_login_check(); Yes it does. But I can't use it. The index() will still end execution even if the statement inside admin_login_check() is true.

Comment: Try changing `admin/login?r2='.$R2` to `/admin/login?r2='.$R2`

Comment: It returns NULL.What's strange is that if I copy all the code from admin_login_check()and paste it in index(), it works fine.

Comment: The issue is not with the condition, its working fine. It just that the redirect does not works.

Comment: Problem is that you're returning a Response object inside a function that is not known by the routing process of CI4.
If you want the redirect to happen, you have to return your `redirect()->to('blabla')` inside your index function because that is the main function you called with your router

Comment: What do you suggest I do to fix this issue? Admin controller might have dozens of methods. Obviously I can't check and redirect separately for every method.

Comment: @NJD Let's look at this the other way... Will you have a case where a method inside your admin controller does not require checking the admin is logged in to use it???

Answer (score 3):

As @ViLar starts to point out, it's how you're returning (or rather not returning) that Response object.

`redirect()->to()` does not perform a redirect immediately, on the spot, when called. It returns an object that in the end, **must be returned by the Controller itself in order to work**.

You are returning that object from `admin_login_check()` to `index()` but then completely ignoring it in `index()`; as such the Controller is never actually receiving or returning the object created by the call to `redirect()`.

If you're going to return redirects from within nested function calls, you need to make sure that Response object returns *all the way up that stack* such that the initial Controller method called actually returns it as well.